# Problem installing Appium@next (Appium 2.0)

Tags: appium, ios-simulator, appium-ios

So far I used Appium 1.x.y which worked pretty well for testing iOS simulator with OS 15.0. After installing XCode 14.0 beta for using iOS simulator with OS 16.0, I discovered I need to start using Appium 2.0 (thank to this thread [Appium Driver does not work on iOS 16](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/17074)). I followed this post ([Installing Appium 2.0](https://appiumpro.com/editions/122-installing-appium-20-and-the-driver-and-plugins-cli)) and ran the command line `npm install -g appium@next` but sadly it failed. These are the errors I am getting.

```
> /Users/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.0/bin/appium -> /Users/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.0/lib/node_modules/appium/index.js

> appium@2.0.0-beta.43 postinstall /Users/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.0/lib/node_modules/appium
> node ./scripts/autoinstall-extensions.js

> /Users/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.0/lib/node_modules/appium/scripts/autoinstall-extensions.js:35
  process.stderr.columns ?? process.stdout.columns ?? 25
                      ^

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I am getting the same errors on a Circle-CI machine:

```
> /Users/distiller/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/appium -> /Users/distiller/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/appium/index.js

> appium@2.0.0-beta.43 postinstall > /Users/distiller/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/appium
> node ./scripts/autoinstall-extensions.js

 > /Users/distiller/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/appium/scripts/autoinstall-extensions.js:35
  process.stderr.columns ?? process.stdout.columns ?? 25
                      ^

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I did not see anything about the need to update any other package.

Comment: You need to update your local Nodejs version because Appium supports 12+ [ref](https://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/?lang=en). Also make sure you uninstalled old Appium with `npm uninstall -g appium` before trying to install 2.0

Comment: Thank you for the response @drunkencheetah. As i mentioned, i got the same error on a circle-ci machine, on which i installed Nodejs 12 and i do not have an existing Appium. The log is attached in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue so installed `2.0.0-beta.42` version of appium.
I followed below steps and was able to install for my requirement.

`nvm use 17.4.0`

Above sets node v17.4.0 and npm v8.3.1

`npm install -g appium@2.0.0-beta.42`